# How to print datetimepicker values to crystal report?

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, datetimepicker

I want to print `FromDate` and `ToDate` values to `Crystal Reports` as well as `TextBox` and `ComboBox` values to `Crystal Reports`. How to print?

Comment: Try to find about `Parameters in Crystal Reports`.